# how to change jest mock function return value in each test?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a mock module like this in my component test file

```
  jest.mock('../../../magic/index', () => ({
    navigationEnabled: () => true,
    guidanceEnabled: () => true
  }));
```

these functions will be called in render function of my component to hide and show some specific feature.

I want to take a snapshot on different combinations of the return value of those mock functions.

for suppose I have a test case like this

```
 it('RowListItem should not render navigation and guidance options', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <RowListItem type="regularList" {...props} />
    );
    expect(enzymeToJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

to run this test case I want to change the mock module functions return values to `false` like this dynamically

```
jest.mock('../../../magic/index', () => ({
    navigationEnabled: () => false,
    guidanceEnabled: () => false
  }));
```

because i am importing `RowListItem` component already once so my mock module wont re import again. so it wont change. how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You can mock the module so it returns spies and import it into your test:

```
import {navigationEnabled, guidanceEnabled} from '../../../magic/index'

jest.mock('../../../magic/index', () => ({
    navigationEnabled: jest.fn(),
    guidanceEnabled: jest.fn()
}));
```

Then later on you can change the actual implementation using `mockImplementation`

```
navigationEnabled.mockImplementation(()=> true)
//or
navigationEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(true);
```

and in the next test

```
navigationEnabled.mockImplementation(()=> false)
//or
navigationEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(false);
```

Comment: Maybe it was not the case at the time, but `jest.mock` needs to be called before doing the import.

Comment: @Sylvain Nothing can/will be called before ES6 imports, they're statically enforced to being first.

Comment: @OlaoyeOluwapelumi You can type it before all you want, but it won't get executed until after the ES6 imports, because they're statically enforced to being treated as first.

Comment: Relevant citation: "But often you need to instruct Jest to use a mock before modules use it. For this reason, Jest will automatically hoist jest.mock calls to the top of the module (before any imports)." From: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Comment: Here's a tutorial that outlines this technique in depth - https://mikeborozdin.com/post/changing-jest-mocks-between-tests/

Comment: Just as a heads up. Do this and then render your component

Answer (score 59):

what you want to do is

```
import { navigationEnabled, guidanceEnabled } from '../../../magic/index';   

jest.mock('../../../magic/index', () => ({
  navigationEnabled: jest.fn(),
  guidanceEnabled: jest.fn()
}));

describe('test suite', () => {
  it('every test', () => {
    navigationEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(value);
    guidanceEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(value);
  });
});
```

you can look more about these functions here =>https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html#mock-return-values

Comment: this does not work with typescript, you will get: Property 'mockReturnValueOnce' does not exist on type '() => string'.

Comment: for TS you need to do `(mockedFn as jest.Mock). mockReturnValueOnce`

Comment: If using `ts-jest`, the `mocked(mockedFn)` wrapper is syntactical sugar for the same thing. https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/docs/user/test-helpers.md#mocked

Comment: really helpful to typescript developers, thank you!!

Comment: This won't work if you have more than 1 call of mocked function in the tested component.

Answer (score 13):

I had a hard time getting the accepted answers to work - my equivalents of `navigationEnabled` and `guidanceEnabled` were undefined when I tried to call `mockReturnValueOnce` on them.

Here's what I had to do:

In `../../../magic/__mocks__/index.js`:

```
export const navigationEnabled = jest.fn();
export const guidanceEnabled = jest.fn();
```

in my `index.test.js` file:

```
jest.mock('../../../magic/index');
import { navigationEnabled, guidanceEnabled } from '../../../magic/index';
import { functionThatReturnsValueOfNavigationEnabled } from 'moduleToTest';

it('is able to mock', () => {
  navigationEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(true);
  guidanceEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(true);
  expect(functionThatReturnsValueOfNavigationEnabled()).toBe(true);
});
```