# How to mock jest function importing from another file as default

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

My question is about how to mock jest function importing from another file as default.

What I want to test is that component using function to enabled Feature (`Features.js`)

I mocked this function using **jest.fn()** and tried to change value using **mockReturnValueOnce**

It looks like below.

mocks/features.js

```
export default function isFeatureEnabled (featureName) {
  return true // want to test both true/false cases 
}
```

test.spec.js

```
jest.mock('__mocks__/features.js', () => ({
  isFeatureEnabled: jest.fn()
}))

describe('isFeatureEnabled', () => {
  it('isFeatureEnabled=[true]', () => {
    isFeatureEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(true)
   // some tests
  })
  it('isFeatureEnabled=[false]', () => {
    isFeatureEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(false)
   // some tests
  })
})
```

When I run the test, I got an error says `mockReturnValueOnce is not a function`. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758366/how-to-change-jest-mock-function-return-value-in-each-test/52279609#52279609) inspired me to implement in this way, however still I cannot figure it out how to make it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close.

Here is a simple working example that demonstrates what you are trying to do:

---

features.js

```
export default function isFeatureEnabled (featureName) {
  // this is the actual implementation...
  return true  // ...but for the example just return true
}
```

__mock__/features.js

```
export default jest.fn(() => true);  // default export is mock that returns true
```

code.js

```
import isFeatureEnabled from './features';

export const funcToTest = () => isFeatureEnabled() ? 'enabled' : 'not enabled';
```

code.test.js

```
import { funcToTest } from './code';
import isFeatureEnabled from './features';

jest.mock('./features');  // use the manual mock

describe('funcToTest', () => {
  it('isFeatureEnabled=[true]', () => {
    isFeatureEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(true);
    expect(funcToTest()).toBe('enabled');  // Success!
  })
  it('isFeatureEnabled=[false]', () => {
    isFeatureEnabled.mockReturnValueOnce(false);
   expect(funcToTest()).toBe('not enabled');  // Success!
  })
})
```

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't expect that I should use `export default jest.fn(() => true)` in the mock.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should test result of you function. Import isFeatureEnabled and test what it returns. I don't get it why you use mock.

```
import isFeatureEnabled from './isFeatureEnabled'

describe('Testing features', () => {

    it('isFeatureEnabled should return true if "add" feature is enabled', () => {
        const feature = 'add'
        const result = isFeatureEnabled(feature)
        expect(result).toEqual(true)
      })
});
```

Comment: thanks, sorry for my lack of explanation, what I want to test is not isFeatureEnabled function but other function relying on isFeaturedEnabled function.

Comment: Ok. So your mock is manual mock in `__mocks__` folder.  In `test.spec.js` simply add `jest.mock(<path to original isFeatureEnabled module>)`

Comment: Please provide funtion you want to test