# How to create jest mock implementation with dynamic return values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mobx

I have defined an action in my mobx store like this:

```
// CardsStore.js

import FetchData from './FetchData';

export default class CardsStore {

  @observable cards = [];

  @action fetchCards = async () => {
    try {
      this.cards = await FetchData();
    } catch (error) {
      // handling error
    }
  };

  ...
  other actions and computed values
  ...
}
```

and this is the implementation for FetchData:

```
import EndpointService from 'app/services/EndpointService';

const endpointService = new EndpointService();

export default async function fetchData() {
  try {
      return await endpointService.getCards();
    } catch (e) {
    return 'caught';
  }
}
```

I have created a mock module for `FetchData` inside __ mocks __ folder that instead of calling the endpoint service returns a hard coded array like this:

```
// ./__mocks__/FetchData.js

const cards = [
  {
    id: 'some-id-1',
    name: 'Test1',
  },
  {
    id: 'some-id-2',
    name: 'Test2',
  },
];

export default function FetchData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  process.nextTick(() =>
  cards ? resolve(cards) : reject({ error: 'Cards are not found.' })
   );
 });
}
```

In my cards.test.js file I test it like this and it works:

```
import CardsStore from './CardsStore.js';

jest.mock('./FetchData');

const cards = [
  {
    id: 'some-id-1',
    name: 'Test1',
  },
  {
    id: 'some-id-2',
    name: 'Test2',
  },
];

describe('when fetch cards is called', () => {

  const cardsStore = new CardsStore();

  it('should load the cards', async () => {
    await cardsStore.fetchCards();
    expect(cardsStore.cards).toEqual(cards);
  });
});
```

The problem is if I want to test my other action `addNewCard` then I need to dynamically change the cards and add a new card and then check to see if the expected cards list is equal to the new one (that should contain 3 cards)

I can't find a way to dynamically update the cards array inside `./__mocks__/FetchData.js`

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45758738/10314151

Answer (score 1):

use jest.spyOn and mockReturnValue...

```
jest.spyOn(cardsStore.prototype, "fetchCards").mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(obj));
```

Replace **obj** with whatever you want to return

example,

```
describe('when fetch cards is called', () => {

  const cardsStore = new CardsStore();

  it('should load the cards', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(cardsStore.prototype, "fetchCards").mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(obj));
    await cardsStore.fetchCards();
    expect(cardsStore.cards).toEqual(cards);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bill for your reply. I tried it but it gives me this error: `Cannot spy the FetchCards property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`. Please also note that I wanted to mock FetchData and not FetchCards action. FetchCards itself doesn't return any value. However, just in case, I tried both and got the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for providing the example. I used it in my code and now it says: `Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`

Comment: Can you try it by changing cardsStore to CardsStore?

Comment: When I change it to CardsStore first I get a lint error saying : `CardsStore is already declared in the upper scope` because I have imported it at the top `import CardsStore from './CardsStore.js';`

And if I ignore it and run it it says : `TypeError: CardsStore is not a constructor`

Comment: if you can upload your code somewhere, i can take a look at it as i am not able to visualize what you have changed